# Read ActiveCell.Address into Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How do I store the address of the active cell in Excel into a variable in Outlook?

Outlook is manipulating a workbook and I want to restore the active cell to its original place after the manipulation.

```
Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set xlB = xl.Workbooks("DWG_CHECKLIST")
reactivateMeSheet = xlB.ActiveSheet.Name
reactivateMeCell = xlB.Sheets(reactivateMeSheet).ActiveCell.Address
```

I have referenced the Excel 15 Object Library.

Comment: Can you post your code Outlook code to see how you're manipulating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be easier if you use a `Range` variable to store the initial cell before your treatment,
that way you'll just have to wrap your code like this :

```
Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set xlB = xl.Workbooks("DWG_CHECKLIST")

Dim reactivateMeCell  As Object 'Excel.Range
xlB.Activate
Set reactivateMeCell = xl.ActiveCell

'''Your code

With reactivateMeCell
    .Parent.Parent.Activate
    .Parent.Activate
    .Activate
End With 'reactivateMeCell
```

Comment: Thank you; I think that's what I was looking for.  ActiveCell appeared in the "xl" IntelliSense dropdown, whereas it didn't before.
This code is triggered when I receive an automatically generated email.  Once I get one of those and ensure it works, I'll mark your answer as correct.  Thanks again!

Comment: Worked perfectly!  My issue was I was declaring reactivateMeCell as a String instead of an Object.

Comment: @isudude17 : Glad I could help! ;)

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveCell` is a Property of the Application

So I think you're looking for

```
Dim reactivateMeCell as String
reactivateMeCell = xlB.ActiveCell.Address
```

or just

```
Dim reactivateMeCell as Object 'Excel.Range
reactivateMeCell = xlB.ActiveCell
```

depending on what you want to declare the variable as.